# Como carregar um metódo assim que a pagina é carregada ? Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directives, ecmascript-5

Tenho um método, `carregarpagina();` que precisa ser carregado assim que a página for carregada. Como faço isso no *Angularjs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente executar a função no final do arquivo

```
$scope.carregarPagina = function() { //implementação do metodo } 
//...... seus outros métodos e atributos
$scope.carregarPagina();
```

Ou usar a diretiva do ngInit para atribuir um valor ao iniciar em um atributo caso necessário.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit